# ReferenceError: d3 is not defined - JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm getting this same error everytime I try to run my JS file on Node. I just got started with this whole thing so I'm probably overlooking some very obvious detail. This is what my HTML head section looks like:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="rooks.css">
    <title>Rooks</title>
    


    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="rooks.js"></script>
    <script src="plotly-2.12.1.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is the error appearing in your browser window or in a console using node?

Comment: @JakeBrowning The error is appearing in the console using node. I have also tried using d3 in my browser window and it doesn’t work either.

Comment: It seem like d3 expects to be run in a browser, which may be why it's not working in node. If you update your question with the browser errors it may be easier to help

Comment: @JakeBrowning thing is, I’m actually not getting any browser errors, it just doesn’t run the code that uses d3. For example, when using sample code from plotly the graph won’t show up if I try to process the data with d3. When hardcoding it, however, it works perfectly fine

Comment: If it frontend or backend program?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski If I’m understanding your question correctly, then it is frontend. As in, the JS file should display a chart on the web browser, but it doesn’t. This only happens when I use d3 to process the data (from a csv file) I want the chart to show. There aren’t any issues when coding the data manually